# Radio button to display Text box if selected and disappear if other option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to add a textarea when a radio button is selected. If another option is then selected I need this textarea to disappear.

I have the following setup

Default.php calls the code so i can include this in any future page

> include 'core/chkbox.php'

4. chkbox.php contains the following

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">  function dynInput(cbox) {   if (cbox.checked) {
>     var input = document.createElement("input");
>     input.type = "text";
>     var div = document.createElement("div");
>     div.id = cbox.name;
>     div.innerHTML = cbox.title;
>     div.appendChild(input);
>     document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);   } else {
>     document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();   } }  </script>
> ```

4. This is then called in the page I am trying to display the radio button in and textarea

>

```
<tr>
            <td><label>Does Change Impact on<br> services?:</label></tr></td>
            <td>

            <input type="radio" class="radio" value="1" name="chg_serviceimpact_ckbx" title="Details:"onclick="dynInput(this);" />Yes
            <input type="radio" class="radio" value="1" name="chg_serviceimpact_ckbx" />No

            <p id="insertinputs" <textarea title="Will services be impact during implementation? Please note outage duration and system" name="chg_serviceimpact" Style="height: 40px" Style="width:400px"></textarea>
                  </p>
                    </></td>                </tr>
```

The issue i have is if Yes is selected then the txt box appears but i am unable to set the size of this box, if no is then selected the text box in not removed, Also if yes is selected twice the text area appears twice.

Any help on deciphering and understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should always contain the text box. Just show/hide it using CSS.

Currently, you're adding a text box each time the corresponding option is selected.

Comment: Might want to empty it as well when it's hidden

Comment: Your*... _just saying_

Comment: @CD001, yes that's true. Otherwise you might run into issues when submitting the form / AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achive this with pure CSS:

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="radio1" name="group" type="radio" />
    <input class="theinput" name="input1" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="radio2" name="group" type="radio" />
    <input class="theinput" name="input2" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="check1" name="group" type="checkbox" />
    <textarea class="theinput" name="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.theinput {
  display: none;  
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .theinput, input[type="radio"]:checked + .theinput {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg7ngxy0/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in your code:

1) Radio buttons are having the same value and name - you won't be able to tell which option is set after you post the data (if you want to post it).

2) Onclick is set to "Yes" element only, you never handle "No" element.

3) You don't handle clicks when your element already appeared.

If you want to continue with "insert or remove" approach, fix your HTML with:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" value="1" name="chg_serviceimpact_ckbx" title="Details:" onclick="dynInput(this);" />Yes
<input type="radio" class="radio" value="0" name="chg_serviceimpact_ckbx" onclick="dynInput(this)" />No
```

And your script by writing:

```
function dynInput(cbox) {   
  var elem = document.getElementById(cbox.name);

  if (cbox.value == 1) {
    // you press 'Yes'
    if (!elem) {
      // check if you already have your input
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = cbox.name;
      div.innerHTML = cbox.title;
      div.appendChild(input);
      document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
    }
  }
  else {
    // you press 'No'
    if (elem) elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
  }

}
```